# Apple push notifications certificate upload issue with sinch sms verification

Tags: ios, sinch, sinch-verification

I have created development and production `APNS` certificates through keychain access. However, when I try to upload `aps.cer` and `aps-development.cer` to the push configuration dashboard at sinch.com, it says:

> Error: Incorrect file type, or file too big. Must be pkcs12 and less than 10kbyte.

I went back to the Apple Developer portal and downloaded the `.cer` files there and tried again to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the certificate to a .pem and then to a .p12.

Follow the steps in here 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Comment: Thanks, once I used keychain to export a .p12 I had no problem uploading it. However, when entering the password I had set on the certificate it wouldn't validate in safari. But when I tried on chrome it worked fine.